# Problem with Solidify in Curves

Tags: modeling, mesh, bezier-curves

New to Blender. I'm trying to thicken a curved mesh. I tried to use the Solidify modifier, but I keep getting these artifacts near one of the curves. I removed double faces, as well as flipped the faces to normals, but the problem remains.

[image: Solidify with Artifacts]

I also noticed in Edit Mode that the edges where the artifacts occur are darker than in the rest of the mesh. Does the problem have something to do with this?

[image]

Comment: Always check first for double vertices, zero-area faces, normals facing the wrong way. Manually drag a vertex at the end of one of the suspect edges, and see if it leaves a hidden one behind.

Comment: Thank you. It was double vertices. I manually removed the extra vertices and now no more artifacts. However, is there a way in Blender 2.80 where I can remove double vertices automatically?

Comment: If the topology is right for it (it usually is) .. in 2.8 it's:,Select all, Alt-M > 'By Proximity'. If you use it a lot, and are prone to carpal tunnel syndrome, you may want to put that in a Quick Menu item, and/or give it a less stretchy key-combination ; )

Comment: Thank you for this. So I'm assuming a good beginner's workflow would be to check for double faces, flipped normals, and double vertices after a mesh is completed?

Comment: There are lots of signs. Face-dots on edges, thicker-looking edges, Ctrl-R refusing to cut a loop, etc..  Also be aware of the most common cause. Right-clicking after an extrude _does not cancel the extrude_. It cancels the move you make afterwards, leaving doubles behind. That's often what you want. But if you want to completely cancel an extrude, use Ctrl-Z.